# Trying to make a pre tag fit\wrap

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, flexbox

Currently the pre tag is wider than the screen on mobile and i can't seem to make it wrap.
Here is a sample of my code:
https://jsfiddle.net/v526rkLm/12/

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 question">
            <span class="qtitle"><h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eaque aut iure ipsum illo qui tempore cumque sapiente! Totam architecto sequi nesciunt maiores eius laudantium dignissimos necessitatibus, aperiam at ullam sed!</h3></span>


<div class="qbody">
    <code><pre>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eaque aut iure ipsum illo qui tempore cumque sapiente! Totam architecto sequi nesciunt maiores eius laudantium dignissimos necessitatibus, aperiam at ullam sed!</pre></code>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

I want it all vertically centered on mobile but no idea how to make it work.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `<pre>` tag has it's [own options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) for handling white space.

- `pre`: Sequences of white space are preserved. Lines are only broken at newline characters in the source and at `<br>` elements.
- `pre-wrap`: Sequences of white space are preserved. Lines are broken at newline characters, at `<br>`, and as necessary to fill line boxes.
- `pre-line`: Sequences of white space are collapsed. Lines are broken at newline characters, at `<br>`, and as necessary to fill line boxes.

You have also set a width value of `max-content` in your CSS. Combined, this prevents the text from wrapping.

Using the following CSS together with a media query to target mobile devices would resolve this:

```
white-space: pre-wrap;
width: 100%;
```